# load an xml from external url to phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to get a value from external url using jquery at phonegap application.

but it's not work, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $("button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Cube').each(function(){

                var usd = $(this).find('Cube type=["currency"]').text();


                $("#d").html(usd);

            });
        }
    });
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="d"></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

is there any way to load / post / get data from/to external url by using:

phonegap, jquery, jquerymobile, ....... ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with phonegap!

Comment: I didn't put the full code with phonegap included js ..
but in general I wanna know how to get data from external url at phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the xml file you can use your url. Since I tried it from browser I created the xml file.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../res/exData.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml){    

                $(xml).find('Cube').each(function(){
                    $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
                         var name = attrib.name;
                         var value = attrib.value;
                         if (name === "currency")
                            $("#d").html(value);
                    });
                 });        

            }, 
            error: function(model, xhr, options) { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

Comment: this code worked fine with internal xml file, but what I need is using external xml file getting data. this give me always alert of error. is there ability to get external xml file?



url: "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

Comment: Is the setting of phonegap allowed to access this url? If yes then it should work, can you print the exact error that you get, probably if using android then you need to have some things like: <access origin=".*"/>  in config.xml and if using iOS then add it to the plist

Comment: I modefied config.xml : 
 `<access origin="*"/>`  
and now it's worked file
**thank you Mr. Sheetal alot..**

Comment: Welcome i am Miss sheetal, he he, anyways please accept this as the answer.